# How to store user credential in firestore after they have signup

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hi  can you please help me I am trying to store user credential in firestore after they have signup  but I keep getting this error

`Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but userDatabase/QMJiHnhoCchs6MKmPFk7wzTrlau1 has 2.`

below is my code
Many thank

`const db = getFirestore(app)`

//Sign up User Method

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword( auth, email, password)
  .then((res) => {
    // Signed in 

   const uid = res.user.uid;

    const data = {
      id:uid,
      email,
       name,
  };



  const ref = collection(db, 'userDatabase',uid)

  console.log(ref);
  setDoc(ref, data)
      .then(() => console.log("Created New User Document Successfully"))
      .catch((e) => console.log("Error" , e));

).catch((e)=>console.log(e))
```

After I commented  all the line from the createUserWithEmailAndPassword I notice that this

`const ref = collection(db, 'userDatabase',uid)`

line was the one generating the error but I can't just figure out why I have tried several methods to resolve this issues which have not work.

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((res) => {
    // Signed in 
    const uid = res.user.uid;

   // const data = {
   //   id:uid,
   //   email,
    //   name,
  //};



  const ref = collection(db, 'userDatabase',uid)

  console.log(ref);
//setDoc(ref, data)
   //   .then(() => console.log("Created New User Document Successfully"))
     // .catch((e) => console.log("Error" , e));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  walk around this issue by replacing the `collection` with `doc`

first make sure you import  doc from firebase/firebase like so

```
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"
```

then Change this

```
const ref = collection(db, 'userDatabase',uid)
```

To

```
const ref = doc(db, 'userDatabase',uid)
```